# Openstack Port Quota, What is effecting this?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Last week I was bit by exceeding my Port limit in Openstack Kilo. I understand how to query, change and in the future will setup my services to notify as this quota is approached...But what is this quota actually limiting?

From the [documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/networking-options-quotas.html): "(IntOpt) Number of ports allowed per tenant. A negative value means unlimited."

Are there a number of virtual iscsi ports this is limiting? If so do I have a physical limit on my hardware that I might exceed if this becomes unlimited?

Or is this a number of IPs that can allocate from a range? (if so, why is it referred to as ports)

In my case the following:

```
[root@_regionOne_ ~]# neutron quota-show --tenant-id _projectUUID_ -c port
+-------+-------+
| Field | Value |
+-------+-------+
| port  | 150   |
+-------+-------+
```

Was altered with:

```
[root@_regionOne_ ~]# neutron quota-show --tenant-id _projectUUID_ --port <new quota limit>
```

To solve the issue. But improving my understanding would be a much better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have an answer to that question, which was also interesting for me.

> **Port:** A port in Neutron represents a virtual switch port on a logical
>   virtual switch. Virtual machine interfaces are mapped to Neutron
>   ports, and the ports define both the MAC address and the IP address 
>   to be assigned to the interface plugged into  them. Neutron port
>   definitions are stored in the Neutron database, which is then used by
>   the receptive plugin agent to build and connect the virtual switching
>   infrastructure.

From the book Learning OpenStack Networking.

Answer (score 0):

The update command should be;

neutron quota-update --tenant-id *projectUUID* --port